# Passing a Mock() into blinker signal.connect() raises "AttributeError: __name__"

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am in the process of refactoring existing code to use the blinker library instead of passing around callback functions. I have a large set of existing tests which make use of mock to check that the callback is fired correctly. However when I try to run the tests against the new code which uses blinker I get an exception from within Mock.

The exception can be easily replicated on the repl and is due to blinker trying to access the `__name__` attribute of the mock.

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> from blinker import signal
>>>
>>> test = signal('test')
>>> m = Mock()
>>>
>>> test.connect(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/base.py", line 113, in connect
      receiver_ref = reference(receiver, self._cleanup_receiver)
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/_utilities.py", line 124, in reference
      weak = callable_reference(object, callback)
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/_utilities.py", line 135, in callable_reference
      return BoundMethodWeakref(target=object, on_delete=callback)
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/_saferef.py", line 143, in __new__
      base.__init__(target, on_delete, *arguments, **named)
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blinker/_saferef.py", line 188, in __init__
      self.func_name = str(im_func.__name__)
  File "/Users/ed/.virtualenvs/iws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 702, in __getattr__
      raise AttributeError(name)
```

MagicMock raises the same exception.

I haven't been able to figure out how to prepare the mock so that the exception is not raised. I could replace the mock with a dummy function and write tests within that but I have over 1000 tests.

Comment: Can you post the code for `connect`? At some point, some attribute of an attribute ... of your mock object is expected to be a function object, which would have an `im_func` attribute. You'll have to properly configure your mock so that it works with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution:

creating a dummy function and passing that to the mock as a spec succeeds.

```
>>> from blinker import signal
>>> from mock import Mock
>>>
>>> def foo():
...     pass
...
>>> t = signal('test')
>>> m = Mock(spec=foo)
>>> m.__name__
<Mock name='mock.__name__' id='4471403152'>
>>> t.connect(m)
<Mock spec='function' id='4471883984'>
>>> t.send()
[(<Mock spec='function' id='4471883984'>, <Mock name='mock()' id='4471404624'>)]
>>> m.called
True
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I get "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Mock' objects" when I call t.connect(m). I am using blinker 1.3 and mock 1.0.0.

Comment: I am using mock 0.8.0 and blinker 1.3 - which works - I will have a quick look at mock 1.0.0

Comment: just tested with mock version 1.0.1 and the example code works

Answer (score 2):

**Shorthand**

```
from mock import MagicMock    
mock_signal = MagicMock(spec={})
```